# Python3 Boolean assignment to multidimension list is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, variable-assignment

Trying to do below

```
visited = [[False] * 3]* 3
print(visited)
visited[0][0] = True
print(visited)
```

why it prints like this:

```
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

shouldn't it be:

```
   [[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
    [[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a 2D array using
`arr = [something * m]*n`, all subarrays point to the same memory location. If you modify even one subarray, all other subarrays get modified.
The correct way to initialise the 2D matrix is
`arr = [[something for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]`
to create a `n x m` matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this means lot of sense .

Comment: If this solves your purpose, consider marking this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give an example how the array works. when you create a contiguous array(below is an example to check what is the size of the integer in python)

```
from sys import getsizeof
getsizeof(bool())
24
```

In my case boolean is 3 bytes (24 / 8 bits). when you define an array like above you are going to get the start location (which is 1000 as per below example) and when you access an array with index  you will be given access to that particular location by the calculation **start_location + size of boolean * index**
1st Index of array will give 1000 + 3 * 1 -> 1003 for example

[image: array define]

In your example visited = [[False] * 3]* 3 we are actually multiplying the reference point.[1000, 1000, 1000] in the example given above. so when you do visited[0][0] = True you are ideally changing the array with reference 1000 and modifying the 0th element to True. since the all array elements point to same array the value becomes like [[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]

you should be using like below to initialize 2D matrix

```
array = [[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
array[0][0] = True
array
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

You would have noticed that by above example we are creating separate arrays on the go (with different references ofcourse).

Comment: Thanks a lot , this means lot of sense .